# Operator Search Puzzle

Tags: c

We have a string "4_3_1_2_6_5_9". We have to find all the combinations of operators, which when they replace the "_" with the operator it gets the number 27.
Some examples:

```
4+3+1-2+6*5-9=27
4*3/1+2/6*5*9=27
4-3*1+2*6+5+9=27
```

I know how to replace the "_" char with operator chars "+-*/", but how would the program even read it?

I don't even know how to begin,some pointers(heh, get it?) at the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: easy *brute-force* solution: 6 operators... 6 loops. `/* pseudo -- not C -- code */ for (op1 in "+-*/") for (op2 in "+-*/") ... expression[1]=op1; expression[3]=op2;...`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for you to get started.

You can get each of the operands in an int by doing something like this:

```
char s[] = "4_3_1_2_6_5_9";
int operands[7];
sscanf(s, "%d_%d_%d_%d_%d_%d_%d", operands, operands+1, ..., operands+6);
```

You might want to try to generate all different combinations of operators. A simple approach would be to have 6 nested for loops, each looping over your 4 available operators and assigning each of them to an underscore:

```
char [] operators = "+-*/";

for (int i0 = 0; i0 < 4; i1++)
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 4; i2++)
...
for (int i5 = 0; i5 < 4; i5++) {
    // here you replace the 1st underscore with operators[i0],
    // the 2nd underscore with operators[i1], 
    // and so on with all 6 of them.
}
```

Then, you need a way to parse the string you've generated to get a result. This isn't so simple, because operators have different precedences (`4*3/1+2/6*5*9` is equal to `((4*3)/1)+((2/6)*5*9)`, for example).

It might be a bit overkill for your problem, but it's still very interesting: You can build an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from each expression, using Dijkstra's [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Those trees are easy to evaluate, and that way you can get the final result.

I hope this points you in the right directions!